# Javascript selectors console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

When I run the code and click on each tab it must print on the console which tab I clicked but it does not print, what is the problem?

```
var main = function() {
    "use strict";

    $(".tabs a span").toArray().forEach(function(element) {

        $(element).on("click", function() {

            var $element = $(element);

            $(".tabs a span").removeClass("active");
            $(element).addClass("active");
            $("main .content").empty();

            if($element.parent().is(":nth-child(1)")) {
                console.log("FIRST TAB CLICKED");
            } else if($element.parent().is(":nth-child(2)")) {

                console.log("SECOND TAB CLICKED");
            } else if($element.parent().is(":nth-child(3)")) {
                console.log("THIRD TAB CLICKED");
            }

            return false;
        });


    });

};
```

Comment: @PredatorIWD He's using `.toArray` so it should work, but yeah it's not idiomatic jQuery

Comment: Please show us your markup and how/where you are calling `main`.

Comment: <main>
   
   <div class = "container">
    <div class = "tabs">
     <a href=""><span class ="active">Newest</span></a>
     <a href=""><span>Oldest</span></a>
     <a href=""><span>Add</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
     </ul>
    
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </main>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the html as formatted markup. And notice that `<main>` is not a valid tag that doesn't cause `main()` to be called?

Answer (score 0):

You want `.parent().parent()` - right now you're looking at the `span`, and the parent of the `span` is an anchor. Not the tab element. It'll clean it up a little to do something like..

```
var $tab = $element.parent().parent();
if($tab.is(".......")) {}
```

It'll speed up the code a little bit too, as you're not checking up the chain on each if statement block.